# Excel macro not working after upgrading to Office 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

My company uses excel to produce network configs that go out to all of our stores.  the configs are pretty much same with the exception of a few variables that get inputted into a variable sheet in Excel.  User then click a command button and voila, the variables are put into the config and a new sheet is created in the workbook.  This was working for us for years.  However, we recently upgraded to Office 2013 and now none of our config templates work. There isn't much to the code so this could be relatively easy but I am not a programmer. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub ReplaceValues(OriginalSheetName As String, VariableSheetName As String, NewSheetName As String)
Dim iVariableRowCounter As String
Dim sSearchValue As String
Dim sReplacementValue As String
Dim iControlCounter As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OriginalSheetName).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = NewSheetName

For iControlCounter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).Shapes(iControlCounter).Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).Shapes(iControlCounter).Delete
    End If
Next

iVariableRowCounter = 2

While ThisWorkbook.Sheets(VariableSheetName).Cells(iVariableRowCounter, 1).Value <> ""
    sSearchValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(VariableSheetName).Cells(iVariableRowCounter, 1).Value
    sReplacementValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(VariableSheetName).Cells(iVariableRowCounter, 2).Value

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).UsedRange.Replace what:=sSearchValue, replacement:=sReplacementValue, searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlPart

    iVariableRowCounter = iVariableRowCounter + 1
Wend
End Sub

Public Function GenerateNewWorksheetName(OriginalSheetName As String) As String
Dim sNewSheetName As String
Dim iIncrement As Integer
Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
Dim bGoodName As Boolean
Dim bSheetFound As Boolean

iIncrement = 1
bGoodName = False

While Not bGoodName
    sNewSheetName = OriginalSheetName & " - " & iIncrement
    bSheetFound = False

    For iSheetCounter = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Name = sNewSheetName Then
            bSheetFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not bSheetFound Then
        bGoodName = True
    End If

    iIncrement = iIncrement + 1
Wend

GenerateNewWorksheetName = sNewSheetName
End Function
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work? Wrong values or are you getting errors? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, that might help. When I click the command button to input the variables, I get a Run-time error '1004': 
Copy method of Worksheet class failed. I get an End button and a Debug button.  when I click the debug button, it highlights this line :
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(OriginalSheetName).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

Comment: What is the line of code that is calling this code? After clicking on Debug, if you hover your mouse over `OriginalSheetName` what does the little pop up say? And is that a name to one of the worksheet in the3 workbook that is running the code?

Comment: Can you post your workbook - with data removed if necessary?

Comment: `Dim iVariableRowCounter As String` should surely be an `Integer` instead of a `String`?

Comment: is your workbook protected? Is your worksheet protected? Are there any hidden worksheets?

Comment: A useful trick, after hitting the Debug button, is to highlight part of the line and hit Shift-F9 to create a "watch". This will keep track of a variable or expression and display the value in memory at the moment. You can create as many watches as you want. I would create a watch for `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)` and see if it is a valid worksheet or not.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an error when you upgrade makes me think that your code might be using early binding (although the only references I see are constants like `msoOLEControlObject` and `xlByColumns`, and I don't know why those would cause Copy to fail). You might need to check the references in VBA, or look into converting to late binding.  Unfortunately, those are a little complex to cover here.

The other possibility is that Copy has changed in the new version of VBA (still on 2007 myself). You should be able to press F1 while the cursor is on the word Copy to find out how it is supposed to work.

Either way you're probably learning a little programming! ;)